# How can I programmatically render a node's field respecting the view mode settings?

Tags: entities, 8

I want to render a node's field inside a block. It works like this:

```
<?php

if ($node) {
  if (isset($node->field_body_secondary) && $field = $node->field_body_secondary->value) {
    $markup = render($field);
    $build = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $markup,
    );
  }
}

return $build;
```

But this is not 100% as if I would just render the field normally, making it visible in the view mode settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the viewmode should be applied to the node, not to the field. So you need to get the viewbuilder and render the node. Afterwards you can pick the rendered array for the field from the node'r render array. Kind of like this:

```
$vb = [EntityTypeManager]->getViewBuilder('node'); // Drupal\node\NodeViewBuilder
$nodeview = $vb->view($node, $viewmode);
$fieldrenderarray = $nodeview[youfield-here];
```

P.S. You need to "[EntityTypeManager]" anyhow injected as @entity_type.manager service. Or get it in your Block-Plugin create() from $container->get('entity_type.manager').

Comment: not quite. `$nodeview` has `#node` as key

Comment: also, this renders the node, not seperate fields

Comment: Yes, I renders the node (and all it's fields). But this is what you adjust in your view mode settings. Maybe I got your question wrong.

Comment: "$nodeview[youfield-here];" is null, at least on Drupal 8.6.x

Comment: Replace "yourfield-here" with the machine name of your field.

Comment: But how to get rid of the title?

Comment: Set it to hidden in the view settings of your node type

Answer (score 50):

To render a single field with the display setting of a view mode you can use the `view()` method of the field:

Example for rendering the image the way it's configured in the node's teaser view-mode:

```
$build['image'] = $node->field_image->view('teaser');
```

Or the body as it's configured in the node's full view-mode:

```
$build['body'] = $node->body->view('full');
```

Or if you want to have more fine-grained control, you can programmatically recreate how Drupal is doing view-modes:

```
$display_options = [
  'label' => 'hidden',
  'type' => 'entity_reference_entity_view',
  'settings' => [
    'view_mode' => 'some_media_image_view_mode',
  ],
];
$build['image'] = $node->field_image->view($display_options);
```

You can figure out the type/settings by inspecting the HTML on the view-modes form (e.g. /admin/structure/types/manage//display/full ) or export the configuration and inspect the YAML files.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not respect the view mode settings, like labels and formatter settings

Comment: This should work, you can even use twig debug with this command. If you provide an existing view mode as string, the field will be formatted with this. If you provide an array you can give your own display settings, for example `['label' => 'inline' ]`

Comment: i believe i tried that already but it didnt work. i will try again. thanks so far

Comment: I find it is respecting the formatter, but not the formatter settings. The output of this includes the correct settings.

Comment: this essentially got me to the answer, where I can get my variable in .twig:
`$vars['var_name'] = $node_object->field_name->view()[0];`

and then in twig, I can render {{ var_name }}

Comment: This only respects field settings if they are actually configured in the display. I.e. if they are defined to not display for the view mode, the settings will be ignored. If you're using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) you can enable a hidden region and configure the fields in that region and this will work how you'd like.

Comment: You don't need a view mode, this answer is about view modes because it was asked. You can provide the field settings on the fly. See for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308253/how-can-i-programmatically-render-the-summary-of-a-textfield

Answer (score 8):

This answer builds on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/208061/394

```
// Designate the field we want to render.
$field_name = 'body';
// Retrieve a render array for that field with the given view mode.
$render_array = $entity->$field_name->view('full');
// Render the result.
\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($render_array);
```

To completely programmatically render the field you finish by calling `renderRoot()`, which establishes a separate render context from what typical page responses would use -- a single render context for a request or sub-request. We could also use `renderPlain()`, but then it would escape all the things.

In the Drush repl but not in normal page execution, this threw a warning for me:

```
PHP warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag drupal-entity invalid in Entity, line: 1 in /drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Html.php on line 286
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [Rainer Feike's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207963/9449) I came to the solution:

```
<?php

public function build() {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $build = array();
  $markup = array();

  $fieldsToRender = array(
    'field_node_ref', 'field_foo', 'field_bar',
  );

  $viewmode = 'default';
  $entityType = 'node';
  $display = entity_get_display($entityType, $node->getType(), $viewmode);
  $viewBuilder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entityType);

  foreach ($fieldsToRender as $field_name) {
    if (isset($node->{$field_name}) && $field = $node->{$field_name}) {
      $fieldRenderable = $viewBuilder->viewField($field, $display->getComponent($field_name));
      if (count($fieldRenderable) &&! empty($fieldRenderable)) {
        $markup[] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($fieldRenderable);
      }
    }  
  }

  if (count($markup)) {
    $build = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => implode("", $markup),
    );
  }

  return $build;

}
```

Using `$viewBuilder->viewField` I can render any fields separately I need. I just need to find out how to add caching depending on the view mode settings, but this is another question :)

Comment: `entity_get_display` is  deprecated as of 8.8.0 and removed in 9.0.0

Use `\Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')->getViewDisplay` as it has the same parameters.

Answer (score 3):

related to [Alex](/users/9449/alex)'s answer, here is how I modified it to use [config_pages](http://drupal.org/project/config_pages) and build a global_footer block:

```
<?php

public function build() {
$config_name = 'global_footer';
$config = config_pages_config($config_name);
$build = array();
$markup = array();

$fieldsToRender = array(
  'field_body', 'field_foo', 'field_bar'
);

$viewmode = 'default';
$entityType = 'config_pages';
$display = entity_get_display($entityType, $config_name, $viewmode);
$viewBuilder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entityType);

foreach ($fieldsToRender as $field_name) {
  if (isset($config->{$field_name}) && $field = $config->{$field_name}) {
    $fieldRenderable = $viewBuilder->viewField($field, $display->getComponent($field_name));
    if (count($fieldRenderable) &&! empty($fieldRenderable)) {
      $markup[] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($fieldRenderable);
    }
  }
}

if (count($markup)) {
  $build = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => implode("", $markup),
  );
}

return $build;

}
```

It's probably better to render arbitrary fields from a config_pages setup as opposed to pulling data from a node, but I guess it really depends on the specific use-case as to which method is best.