# How to add a view mode caching dependency in my custom block?

Tags: 8, caching, entities

[I have a block which renders fields of a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207959/how-can-i-programmatically-render-a-nodes-field-respecting-the-view-mode-settin). The output of each field is controlled in the view mode settings of the node entity. Now, how can I add caching which is depended on the view mode settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out :)

Using `entity_get_display` to actually load the display view settings of the current node and then just merge the tags:

```
<?php

public function getCacheTags() {
  if ($node = $this->getNode()) {
    $cacheTags = Cache::mergeTags(parent::getCacheTags(), array('node:' . $node->id()));
    $display = $this->getEntityViewDisplay(); // function which uses entity_get_display
    $cacheTags = Cache::mergeTags($display->getCacheTags(), $cacheTags);
  }
  else {
    $cacheTags = parent::getCacheTags();
  }

  return $cacheTags;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using the ctools view entity block, that accepts a node as context and renders it in a given view mode.

Comment: @Berdir I dont want all the visible view mode fields in that specific block - if that makes any sense

Comment: You can always make a new view mode that only contains the fields that you want.

Comment: But that sounds like an overhead of view modes, doesnt it?