# How can I programmatically render the summary of a textfield?

Tags: entities

I can output a textarea field with the following code:

```php
$entity->fieldname->view();
```

How do I need to change that code for getting the *summary* of that field?

(Where can I find a documentation of that view-function?)

Comment: The documentation is here: [FieldItemBase::view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemBase.php/function/FieldItemBase%3A%3Aview/8.2.x) and it points to [EntityViewBuilderInterface::viewFieldItem](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityViewBuilderInterface%3A%3AviewFieldItem/9.3.x) for the available options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the field formatter `text_summary_or_trimmed`:

```
$build[] = $entity->fieldname->view([
  'label' => 'hidden',
  'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed',
  'settings' => [
    'trim_length' => 600,
  ],
]);
```

The easiest way to find the field formatter name and settings is configuring a field in a display mode of a content type and exporting the configuration.

How to find the documenation, see [How to apply a Field Formatter to a node field programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/240002/how-to-apply-a-field-formatter-to-a-node-field-programmatically)